# My "if statements" do not run, even though the parameters are true

Tags: java, if-statement

Ok, so my code will compile as if there are no errors, but then the code that should be executed will not truly run. Please help.

```
public static void newGameCheck()   {
    String newCharacter = scan.next();
    if (newCharacter.equals("New game"))    {
    //more code here, but it does not get executed for some reason
    }
```

And another example is here:

```
public static void warriorTurn()    {
    if (warriorAlive==true) {
        etut.choosingTarget();
        int target= scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Now type in which ability you want him to use, make sure to use capitals");
        warrior_Weapons_and_Abilities();


String ability= scan.next();
            if (ability.equals("Anduril, Foe of Terror"))   {
                int damage= 100+((int) (Math.random()*50));
                etut.loseHealth(target, damage);
                mana2=mana2-0;
                etut.displayHealth(target);         
            }
            else if (ability.equals("Aethereal Blades"))    {


int damage= 250+((int) (Math.random()*100));
                etut.loseHealth(target, damage);
                mana2=mana2-2;
                etut.displayHealth(target);             
            }
            else if (ability.equals("Potion"))  {
            health2=health2+100;
            mana=mana-0;
            etut.displayHealth(target);




    }
```

Here^, whenever I type in the ability name, the code still will not execute

Comment: Please add the relevant language tag to your question.

Comment: Did you step through the code in a debugger?

Comment: Debug your program.

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change all `scan.next()` to `scan.nextLine()`. `scan.next()` only will read one word.

Answer (score 0):

The next() method on Scanner returns the next token.  It's probably just returning the first word, unless you have the delimiter set to newline.